# Whitelist GoogleUpdate.exe in Firewall settings on Ubuntu system

Tags: wine, firewall, executable, google-drive

I am trying to install Google Drive's 'Backup and sync' on my Ubuntu 18.04 but as this is not available for Linux systems. I am using Wine to install Window's exe file. So while running the exe file, it shows the error, 'Unable to connect to internet, if you use firewall, whitelist GoogleUpdate.exe'. I don't know how to whitelist some app in Firewall on Ubuntu. So, Please help me with this.

My basic goal is to be able to sync one of my folders on Ubuntu system with Google Drive automatically. So if you have some other way for doing this, please suggest me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu's firewall is disabled by default

Comment: Thanks @Android Dev for the reply. I checked status of firewall using sudo ufw status and it's active.